# JavaFX - TableColumn graphic higher than other rows

Tags: java, javafx, graphic, tablecolumn

I am making a table with JavaFX. Every row has text. One row has a graphic because the text of that cell has multiple colors.

The code only applies when a certain condition is true (that part works):

```
departTimeCol.setCellFactory(column -> new TableCell<Ride, String>() {
            @Override
            protected void updateItem(String item, boolean empty) {
                super.updateItem(item, empty);

                setText(item);

                if(item != null && ! empty){
                    if(item.matches("^([0-9]|0[0-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]\\s\\+[\\d]")) {
                        Text timeText = new Text(item.split(" ")[0].trim() + " ");
                        Text delayText = new Text(item.split(" ")[1].trim());

                        delayText.setFill(Color.RED);

                        TextFlow flow = new TextFlow(timeText, delayText);

                        setText(null);
                        setGraphic(flow);

                    }
                }
            }
        });
```

The result is:

[image: Result]

The row with the red +2 is the graphic. All the other rows contain text. How can I give the row - containing a graphic - the same height?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply set the prefered height to `0` to make the height just what is needed to store the text.

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("((?:[0-9]|[01][0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]\\s)(\\+\\d)");

departTimeCol.setCellFactory(column -> new TableCell<Ride, String>() {

    private final Text timeText = new Text();
    private final Text delayText = new Text();
    private final TextFlow flow = new TextFlow(timeText, delayText);

    {
        delayText.setFill(Color.RED);
        flow.setPrefHeight(0);
        flow.heightProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
            this.setMinHeight(newValue.doubleValue() + 4);
        });
        flow.setMinHeight(Region.USE_COMPUTED_SIZE);
        setContentDisplay(ContentDisplay.GRAPHIC_ONLY);
        setGraphic(flow);
    }

    @Override
    protected void updateItem(String item, boolean empty) {
        super.updateItem(item, empty);

        if (empty || item == null) {
            timeText.setText("");
            delayText.setText("");
            delayText.setVisible(false);
        } else {
            Matcher m = pattern.matcher(item);
            if (m.matches()) {
                timeText.setText(m.group(1));
                delayText.setText(m.group(2));
                delayText.setVisible(true);
            } else {
                timeText.setText(item);
                delayText.setText("");
                delayText.setVisible(false);
            }
        }

    }
});
```

Note that there are a few more things in the code that should be fixed:

- You never set the graphic back to `null`, even if the `String` no longer matches the regex or if the cell becomes empty. This means you can get the `TableCell` into a state where the `text` property is not empty and the `graphic` contains a `TextFlow`. **Note:** Always make sure the state of the look of a cell is correct no matter how often the `updateItem` method is called and independent of the arguments passed.
- You produce a inconsistent look by using the `graphic` + a `TextFlow` for one case and the `text` property for another. (Just take a look at the leftmost part of the text in your screenshot! Those are not properly aligned).
- The whole purpose of using `Cell`s is reusing the node to prevent unnecessary creation of nodes. You kind of ruin this attempt by recreating the `TextFlow`, ect. in the `updateItem` method instead of reusing those nodes.
- The regex needs not start with `^` since `matches` already makes sure the whole input is matched. Furthermore the delimiter used for `split` does not have an exact equivalent in the regex. There are other space chars than , such as tab. Just check what the following code does...

  ```
  System.out.println("a\tb".matches(".\\s."));
  System.out.println("a\tb".split(" ")[1]);
  ```

  You can also parse the input and match it in the same step by using `Pattern`+`Matcher` and capturing groups. This way you also do not have the issue mentioned above.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried your solution, but +2 does not become red :/